# Trouble with wstringstream

Tags: c++, string

I have a wstringstream:

```
wstringstream sstream;
AlterSstream(sstream);

wstringstream bar_stream;

bar_stream << sstream;
bar_stream << "foo";

MessageBoxW(
  NULL,
  bar_stream.str().c_str(),
  L"subject",
  MB_OK
);
```

This outputs a long string that looks nothing like what I put in it in `AlterSstream()`:

```
00000000002CEC58foo
```

AlterSstream:

```
void AlterSstream(wstringstream& outStream)
{
    outStream << "odp";
}
```

Why is this happening? If I print out `sstream` directly, it works fine, but printing out `bar_stream` creates the problem. I'm guessing that the `<<` operator doesn't work the way I think it does between two streams?

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I had  left a bit of code out originally. It is fixed above.

Comment: Are you sure `AlterSstream` is not adding "00000000002CEC58" to the stream?

Comment: @GMan and @RSK - updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload to copy from stream to stream.
You need to change the line:

```
bar_stream << sstream;
```

to:

```
bar_stream << sstream.str();
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the compiler selected the version of `operator<<` that accepts a `void*` argument and prints its 64-bit address in hexadecimal. The text-printing version of `operator<<` is a template that takes the same kind of character as the stream's representation, which in your case is `wchar_t`. You've passed it an array of `char`; use a wide-character literal instead, as [Swegi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010483/c-trouble-with-wstringstream/3010549#3010549) suggests:

```
outStream << L"odp";
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but then why does the compiler pick the right overload for sstream << "foo";? The only difference is that op<< "odp" is called with the reference to sstream in the Alterstream function.

Comment: On the other hand, if the compiler used the `void*` version inside `AlterSstream`, then it should have also selected that version for inserting `foo`. I have no explanation for the different behaviors. Are you sure you copied and pasted your real code into your question?

Comment: Actually, I didn't copy the code entirely correctly. I have corrected the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `L"odp"`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with your update you revealed the problem:

bar_stream << sstream;

wstringstream is:

```
typedef basic_stringstream<wchar_t> wstringstream;
```

basic_stringstream is-a basic_iostream, which is-a basic_ostream (and a basic_istream, but we don't care about that part) which is-a basic_ios which is-a ios_base.

But there's no `basic_ostream& operator<<(basic_ostream&);`; I'm not sure which overload the compiler is using, but it appears from the output to be basic_stringstream& basic_stringstream::operator<<(void *p), which outputs the pointer's value in hex.

If you want to copy the sstream's data, use the wstringstream ctor that takes a const basic_string. passing it a copy of the original wstringstream's internal string:

```
wstringstream bar_stream( sstream.str() ) ;
```